# How Can I Add an Action To A Icon on a Graphical Table on Spotfire Using IronPython

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, tibco

I'm trying to create an IronPython script that can remove all the columns from my Graphical Table, add a column with Icons and assign a specific action to this icon whenever it's clicked.

Unfortunately, I still have not found on Spotfire API the part on how to add the action programmatically.

Here is my current core:

```py
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals.Miniatures import *

from System.Drawing import Color

for vis in Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals:
    if vis.Title == 'Selected Period':
        viz = vis.As[GraphicalTable]()

# Remove all columns:
        for c in viz.Columns:
            viz.Columns.Remove(c)

# Add Icon Column
        (status,NewColumn) = viz.Columns.AddNew[IconMiniatureVisualization]()
        NewColumn.AutoConfigure()
        NewColumn.Title = 'Icon'
        NewColumn.IconAxis.Rules.Clear()
        NewColumn.IconAxis.Rules.AddExpressionRule("1=1", Color.FromName("Green"), MarkerShape(MarkerType.Plus))
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: oh wow, solid question... my experience has been that Action Controls are not really addressed by the API. I would imagine that it's similar for onClick events for Graphical Tables, unfortunately. I did some quick searching and there is an Action property ( https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.12.0/doc/api/html/P_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Visuals_Miniatures_MiniatureVisualizationDetails_Action.htm ), but not a lot of expose on its use.

Comment: there's also a KpiVisualizationActionContext ( https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.12.0/doc/api/html/T_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Visuals_KpiVisualizationActionContext.htm ) but I don't have the impression that it's the same -- I know it's for a different chart type but sometimes these things can be revealing. I would definitely try to set an action and then read that Action property. as a workaround, what if you either copied the visual from another page or something like that?

Comment: ah, finally, there's the ScriptManager class ( https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.12.0/doc/api/html/T_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Scripting_ScriptManager.htm ) which may lead you down the right path... sorry that I can't take the time to give a more direct answer. I hope you'll share whatever solution you come up with!!

Comment: Thanks for the links, niko. Will have a look and, if/when I find the answer, will share it here.